Sync two sheets, but 2nd sheet only pulls a subset of data based on the next 14 days starting from today
I have been reading and trying various solutions and have not come even close to getting what I need.
I have a 'Working' sheet where I have pulled in responses from a google form. The form response sheet is left alone. Everything is copied to Working and that sheet is where I manipulate the info to get everything I need.
The problem though is that the Working sheet is a lot! I need someone who doesn't know anything to get work done using this information.
So I created what I call a Dashboard. I know, most people want a dashboard to be something else. In my case, it is a smaller set of data, only the next 14 days, starting from today. So it changes every day what info is pulled from the Working sheet. I have been using a query formula to pull what I need. If you look at my sheets, some of the 'buttons' on the left side are not active because I haven't figured that part out yet.
I need to be able to have the next 14 days sync into the Dashboard AND allow me to make changes. Using a query I can't change drivers or buses or anything else, I have to go to the Working sheet to make changes. So using a formula will not work. I need all changes to also sync back to the Working sheet. I'm talking about 2-way sync between sheets. Also, the cells to sync from Working to Dashboard are not the same cells/columns.
Please, help would be very appreciated!
Here is my test sheet.
Here is the code I have tried most recently because I really thought this was the one!
function onEdit(e) {
  var sheetName = ['Working', 'Dashboard',];  // name of sheets
  var firstCell = ['W', 'B'];    // First pair of cells to sync
  var secondCell = ['X', 'C'];    // Second pair of cells to sync
  var thirdCell = ['AC', 'D'];    // First pair of cells to sync
  var fourthCell = ['S', 'E'];    // Second pair of cells to sync
  var fifthCell = ['T', 'F'];    // First pair of cells to sync
  var sixthCell = ['Q', 'G'];    // Second pair of cells to sync
  var seventhCell = ['AF', 'H'];    // First pair of cells to sync
  var eightCell = ['R', 'I'];    // Second pair of cells to sync
  var r = e.range;
  var ss = e.source;
  var value = (e.value === undefined ? "" : e.value);
  var i = sheetName.indexOf(r.getSheet().getSheetName()); 
  if (i > -1 && r.getA1Notation() == firstCell[i]) {
    for (var k = 0; k < sheetName.length; k++) {
      if (k != i) {
        ss.getSheetByName(sheetName[k]).getRange(firstCell[k]).setValue(value);
      }
    }
  }
  if (i > -1 && r.getA1Notation() == secondCell[i]) {
    for (var k = 0; k < sheetName.length; k++) {
      if (k != i) {
        ss.getSheetByName(sheetName[k]).getRange(secondCell[k]).setValue(value);
      }
    }
  }
}


Welcome to Web Applications Stack Exchange. To learn scripting, see the resources at Apps Script at Stack Overflow and Clean Code JavaScript. To hire a Google Apps Script consultant to work on your project, check out this register of consultants.


I need to be able to have the next 14 days sync into the Dashboard AND allow me to make changes.

Approach 1: filter views
One approach would be to automatically append incoming form responses in the bottom of 'Working' with a script, and use a filter view to limit visible rows to the next 14 days. This way, you would not need to implement a two-way sync and avoid a lot of complexity.
Approach 2: two-way sync
To do what you are asking also sounds doable, but it's not simple, and there are many edge cases to take into account. You cannot use a query() formula to get the data, because formula results are always view-only. The data needs to be read and written with scripts, and there are two main parts to this.
First, you apparently want to add form responses to Dashboard automatically as new responses come in. An onEdit(e) simple trigger is not suitable for this. Use an installable "on form submit" trigger instead. To add data automatically in Dashboard when a new response comes in, read the data in the response, reorder it as required, and write the resulting row to Dashboard.

To add new data to the bottom of Dashboard, use Sheet.appendRow().

To insert data in the middle of Dashboard, use Sheet.insertRows() and Range.setValues().

To delete a row, use Sheet.deleteRow().


See my moveRowsFromSpreadsheetToSpreadsheet_ script for sample code.
Second, you apparently want to copy any changes made in Dashboard back to Working. Use an onEdit(e) simple trigger. Identify the row where to write by doing a lookup using a unique ID that is present in both sheets. You can use the form response timestamp as the unique ID.
This is not a simple undertaking and will require some actual programming.

So I don't actually want the form responses to come into the Dashboard. Form responses go into their own sheet and are not touched. Each new submission is imported via a script I run manually every morning, so I can see what is new. There are a ton of formulas on the Working page that manipulate that date so my calendar events get all the data I need in it and field trips sheets can be created and other things.

You're correct, it is a good practice to never touch form responses, and neither of these recipes suggests that you modify anything in that tab. The filter view recipe above discusses the Working tab. The two-way sync recipe above tells how to copy new data into Dashboard, and then back to Working. Syncing is tricky, so I would recommend the filter view approach.

I'm looking at the filter view option now. I cannot figure out how to make it show the next 14 days of data.  I was looking at a formula, but my headers have formulas built into the header text, so as to keep the formulas out of the rows of data. That solution has been excellent, I don't want to mess with the headers. the point is I think those formulas were messing with being able to use another formula on that same data. Next I turned on filtering and was looking at conditional filter thru that menu. Even a custom filter. So far I haven't figured it out.

Ok, I think I got it... just took a little more thinking. I used this formula in the Filter by condition section in the filter menu: =AND(W2:W>=TODAY(), W2:W<=TODAY()+14)
